# Html.ValidationSummary display custom validation error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view (skipping redundant code):

```
@model ListinoTariffeViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Impossibile salvare. Correggi gli errori:", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    
     @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tariffe.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Tariffe[i])
    }
}
```

where the model class is :

```
public class ListinoTariffeViewModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime DataInizio { get; set; }

    public List<TariffaOrariaLivelloViewModel> Tariffe { get; set; }
}
```

When I submit, if validation fails inside EditorFor, ValidationSummary shows the list of all validation messages for each item coming from EditorFor.
This is the screenshot of the  view, where EditorFor is a single of the table:

[image]

I don't want to show all repeating error messages, so applying the style below I can get a single error message:

```
<style>
   .validation-summary-errors ul 
   {
      display: none;
   }
</style>
```

[image]

This is good when user don't fill in all values, but I need also to show another error message when the user insert the date but it is not valid.

My business rules says that the date entered must be later than the previous one saved.
With my code the error message is not explanatory.

[image]

This is my controller code:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{

    var tariffePrecedenti = db.TariffeOrarieLivello.Where(x => x.DataFine == null).ToList();
    if (tariffePrecedenti.Any())
    {
        var t = tariffePrecedenti[0];
        if (viewModel.DataInizio <= t.DataInizio)
        {
            // more explanatory message !!! But it's not displayd cause the applied style 
            ModelState.AddModelError("dateerror", string.Format("Data inizio deve essere successiva a {0}", t.DataInizio.Date.ToString()));
            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }


    var tariffe = viewModel.Tariffe.Select(t => new TariffaOrariaLivello()
    {
        IdLivello = t.IdLivello,
        DataInizio = viewModel.DataInizio,
        StraordinarioDiurno = t.StraordinarioDiurno,
        StraordinarioNotturno = t.StraordinarioNotturno,
        StraordinarioFestivoNotturno = t.StraordinarioFestivoNotturno
    }).ToList();

    db.TariffeOrarieLivello.AddRange(tariffe);


    if(tariffePrecedenti!=null)
    {
        tariffePrecedenti.ForEach(t => t.DataFine = viewModel.DataInizio.AddDays(-1));
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
else
{
   
   ModelState.AddModelError("valerror", "Impossibile salvare. Inserire tutti i campi.");
   return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: For your case, I would suggest you to take a look into  [Unobtrusive validation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-unobtrusive-validation-in-jquery/) which is usually the trend now. Validation summaries have been out of trend for a long time except for some cases.